# How to signal select() to return immediately?

Tags: c, multithreading, select, sockets

I have a worker thread that is listening to a TCP socket for incoming traffic, and buffering the received data for the main thread to access (let's call this socket *A*). However, the worker thread also has to do some regular operations (say, once per second), even if there is no data coming in. Therefore, I use `select()` with a timeout, so that I don't need to keep polling. (Note that calling `receive()` on a non-blocking socket and then sleeping for a second is not good: the incoming data should be immediately available for the main thread, even though the main thread might not always be able to process it right away, hence the need for buffering.)

Now, I also need to be able to signal the worker thread to do some other stuff immediately; from the main thread, I need to make the worker thread's `select()` return right away. For now, I have solved this as follows (approach basically adopted from [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-May/147063.html) and [here](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=5154)):

At program startup, the worker thread creates for this purpose an additional socket of the datagram (UDP) type, and binds it to some random port (let's call this socket *B*). Likewise, the main thread creates a datagram socket for sending. In its call to `select()`, the worker thread now lists both *A* and *B* in the `fd_set`. When the main thread needs to signal, it `sendto()`'s a couple of bytes to the corresponding port on `localhost`. Back in the worker thread, if *B* remains in the `fd_set` after `select()` returns, then `recvfrom()` is called and the bytes received are simply ignored.

This seems to work very well, but I can't say I like the solution, mainly as it requires binding an extra port for *B*, and also because it adds several additional socket API calls which may fail I guess – and I don't really feel like figuring out the appropriate action for each of the cases.

I think ideally, I would like to call some function which takes *A* as input, and does nothing except makes `select()` return right away. However, I don't know such a function. (I guess I could for example `shutdown()` the socket, but the side effects are not really acceptable :)

If this is not possible, the second best option would be creating a *B* which is much dummier than a real UDP socket, and doesn't really require allocating any limited resources (beyond a reasonable amount of memory). I guess [Unix domain sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_sockets) would do exactly this, but: the solution should not be much less cross-platform than what I currently have, though some moderate amount of `#ifdef` stuff is fine. (I am targeting mainly for Windows and Linux – and writing C++ by the way.)

Please don't suggest refactoring to get rid of the two separate threads. This design is necessary because the main thread may be blocked for extended periods (e.g., doing some intensive computation – and I can't start periodically calling `receive()` from the innermost loop of calculation), and in the meanwhile, someone needs to buffer the incoming data (and due to reasons beyond what I can control, it cannot be the sender).

Now that I was writing this, I realized that someone is definitely going to reply simply "[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)", so I just had my first look at it... Couldn't find an obvious solution, though. Do note that I also cannot (easily) affect how socket *A* is created, but I should be able to let other objects wrap it, if necessary.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are almost there. Use a ["self-pipe" trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html). Open a pipe, add it to your `select()` read and write `fd_set`, write to it from main thread to unblock a worker thread. It is portable across POSIX systems.

I have seen a variant of similar technique for Windows in one system (in fact used together with the method above, separated by `#ifdef WIN32`). Unblocking can be achieved by adding a dummy (unbound) datagram socket to `fd_set` and then closing it. The downside is that, of course, you have to re-open it every time.

However, in the aforementioned system, both of these methods are used rather sparingly, and for unexpected events (e.g., signals, termination requests). Preferred method is still a variable timeout to `select()`, depending on how soon something is scheduled for a worker thread.

Comment: Thanks, but as specified in the question, the eventual solution should work in Windows too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the Windows suggestion. Any idea how expensive the re-opening in practice is?

Comment: Thanks Checkers, creating and closing the (non-bound) socket seems to work very well indeed.

Comment: I don't have any hard numbers, but since you are writing for Windows, it almost always means desktop, which means the cost should be negligible.

Comment: Under Windows you could also just keep a UDP socket open and send a packet to it to make select() return ready-for-read on that socket, or you can create a pair of TCP sockets that are connected to each other and send a byte on one of them while `select()` is monitoring the other one.

Answer (score 3):

Using a pipe rather than socket is a bit cleaner, as there is no possibility for another process to get hold of it and mess things up.

Using a UDP socket definitely creates the potential for stray packets to come in and interfere.

An anonymous pipe will never be available to any other process (unless you give it to it).

You could also use signals, but in a multithreaded program you'll want to make sure that all threads except for the one you want have that signal masked.

Answer (score 1):

On unix it will be straightforward with using a pipe. If you are on windows and want to keep using the select statement to keep your code compatible with unix, the trick to create an unbound UDP socket and close it, works well and easy. But you have to make it multi-threadsafe.

The only way I found to make this multi-threadsafe is to close and recreate the socket in the same thread as the select statement is running. Of course this is difficult if the thread is blocking on the select. And then comes in the windows call QueueUserAPC. When windows is blocking in the select statement, the thread can handle Asynchronous Procedure Calls. You can schedule this from a different thread using QueueUserAPC. Windows interrupts the select, executes your function in the same thread, and continues with the select statement. You can now in your APC method close the socket and recreate it. Guaranteed thread safe and you will never loose a signal.

Answer (score 0):

To be simple:
a global var saves the socket handle, then close the global socket, the `select()` will return immediately: `closesocket(g_socket);`

Comment: This only works in Windows, not in Linux. In Windows it returns and you get the error WSAENOTSOCK. In Linux select keeps blocking.