# How to cancel waiting in select() on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sockets, winsock

In my program there is one thread (receiving thread) that is responsible for receiving requests from a TCP socket and there are many threads (worker threads) that are responsible for processing the received requests. Once a request is processed I need to send an answer over TCP.

And here is a question. I would like to send TCP data in the same thread that I use for receiving data. This thread after receiving data usually waits for new data in `select()`. So once a worker thread finished processing a request and put an answer in the output queue it has to signal the receiving thread that there are data to send. The problem is that I don't know how to cancel waiting in `select()` in order to get out of waiting and to call `send()` .

Or shall I use another thread solely for sending data over TCP?

**Updated**

MSalters, Artyom thank you for you answers!

MSalters, having read your answer I found this site: [Winsock 2 I/O Methods](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediomethod5.html) and read about `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`. My program in fact must work both on HP-UX and Windows I finally decided to use the approach that had been suggested by Artyom.

Comment: Why do you use `select()` for writing ? Usually, `select()` just waits for received data, and you can `send()` data using the same socket(s) meanwhile.

Comment: No, I don't use select for writing. Did I say that?

Comment: @skwllsp: I assumed it since you seem to want to cancel `select()` to write to your socket, which is not necessary. But perhaps I misunderstood the whole thing, my english is not exactly native.

Comment: Why do you want to write to the socket from the thread that you have blocked in select() waiting for more read data when you say you have many worker threads that are responsible for processing the requests. Why not simply write directly from the worker thread. A socket is thread-safe for this kind of usage pattern.

Comment: Do you mean that a few worker threads can safely call `::send()` at the same time an it is OK? That is probably also a solution. However as for my question I simply did not know how to do in my way. I mean that even though my idea might be not optimal I don't know to implement it.

Comment: If you are sending a response message such that it is a single send from then if you have multiple threads issuing sends you'll get a series of complete messages (subject to the normal rules of reading from a tcp stream) but you wont know the order of the complete messages as the worker threads could issue their sends at any point. So, three threads sending AAA, BBB and CCC could result in AAABBBCCC BBBCCCAAA CCCBBBAAA etc but never ABACABACCB. Note that if each thread issues multiple sends that make up a single logical message; so A A A, B B B, C C C then your messages will be garbled.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use something similar to safe-pipe trick, but in your case you need to use a pair of connected TCP sockets.

1. Create a pair of sockets.
2. Add one to the select and wait on it as well
3. Notify by writing to other socket from other threads.
4. Select is immediately waken-up as one of the sockets is readable, reads all the
   data in this special socket and check all data in queues to send/recv

How to create pair of sockets under Windows?

```
inline void pair(SOCKET fds[2])
{
    struct sockaddr_in inaddr;
    struct sockaddr addr;
    SOCKET lst=::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    memset(&inaddr, 0, sizeof(inaddr));
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    inaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    inaddr.sin_port = 0;
    int yes=1;
    setsockopt(lst,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char*)&yes,sizeof(yes));
    bind(lst,(struct sockaddr *)&inaddr,sizeof(inaddr));
    listen(lst,1);
    int len=sizeof(inaddr);
    getsockname(lst, &addr,&len);
    fds[0]=::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    connect(fds[0],&addr,len);
    fds[1]=accept(lst,0,0);
    closesocket(lst);
}
```

Of course some checks should be added for return values.

Comment: `(char*)&yes,sizeof(yes)` ?? new to me :)

Comment: @sarnold  Unlike POSIX setsockopt, windows one receives `char const *` as value instead of `void const *` as on POSIX platforms.

Comment: You don't really need a pair of sockets, you can use a single UDP socket, "connected" to itself.

Comment: @Hasturkun, I am facing the similar issue where, I want my `select()` to return when internet goes off. I am reading that in Unix we should use "self pipe trick" and in Windows we should use some "socket trick". The UDP socket connected to itself seems good. As it will work in both the platform. Is there any place, where I can see the code example for the same?

Comment: @iammilind: I don't have code available, but the implementation is rather simple. Create a UDP socket, `bind()` it to `INADDR_LOOPBACK` and port 0, use `getsockname()` to get its address, then `connect()` it to that address. You now have a self-connected UDP socket, which you can `select()`/read/write on as needed.

Comment: @Hasturkun, is the binding really required for UDP? Why port 0? I thought that simple `::sendto()` should work. Have you tried or seen elsewhere being done?

Comment: @iammilind: The binding is so you can connect the socket predictably to itself (you likely won't get anything useful out of `getsockname()` unless the socket is bound, and you don't want anything else attaching to it). Binding port 0 will select a port dynamically (While using `connect()` ensures that nothing else can send messages to the socket, so you don't need to filter out messages yourself). I've personally used this on Windows in the past,

Answer (score 7):

`select` is not the native API for Windows. The native way is [WSAWaitForMultipleEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742219.aspx). If you use this to create an alertable wait, you can use [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684954.aspx) to instruct the waiting thread to send data. (This might also mean you don't have to implement your own output queue)

Comment: What you are suggesting is to use IOCP that have many drawbacks and... unless you handle 10000 connections it is better to avoid them.

Comment: Well, IOCP's are one way to break out of a WSAWaitForMultipleEvents. You can also add an Event to the list of objects waited on, and signal the event when there's data to send. I don't recall problems with the combination of WaitForMultipleEvents/QueueUserAPC, though, that's why I suggested it.

Comment: Artyom, what are the 'many drawbacks' of IOCP then? Not that I'm suggesting that they're the solution to either the original question or this particular issue; I'm just curious as to what you think is hard about IOCP based communication..

Comment: @Len Holgate, the problem that IOCP generally does not cover many aspects of socket programming, for example, you can't do asynchronous connect with IOCP and you can do it with select, so in complex TCP/IP cases you may find yourself using threads, IOCP and select in order to solve such kind of problems, so unless you have very big number of sockets to manage, select is more appropriate.

Comment: @Artyom: you're missing the point then. The IOPC is used only behind the scenes, for the cross-thread `QueueUserAPC` interrupting; `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` waits for sockets in the same way as `select()` does.

Comment: @Artyom - er, yes you can, `ConnectEx()` is fully async and operates with IOCP, likewise `AcceptEx()` is also fully async and allows you to accept connections on your IOCP threads and so removes the need for a listen thread. I respectfully suggest you take another look as it sounds like you knowledge of IOCP is either out of date or is just incorrect. IMHO select is only more appropriate if you feel you need some level of cross platform portability.

Comment: @Len Holgate, I see your point, indeed ConnectEx exist from Windows XP and above, I just wonder, why Boost.Asio still uses select for asynchronous connect implementation? It has very good support of Windows and even supports new features of Vista/Winodows 7 but it still prefers using additional thread+select over using ConnectEx+IOCP when it uses IOCP for everything but connect: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html

Comment: Lazy backwards compatibility (if they support XP and don't bother to selectively enable more advanced functionality when it's available)? Ignorance? Failure to update working code when new functionality becomes available? Who knows.

Comment: @Len Holgate, it is unlikely, as Boost.Asio usually implements best techniques, so I assume there was some reason.

Comment: @Artyom - assume makes an ass, etc. If they do have a reason then it would be sensible for them to document it. Personally, I've not had any problems with `ConnectEx()` (except of my own making) and I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 4):

See also this post:
[How to signal select() to return immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384391/how-to-signal-select-to-return-immediately)

For unix, use an anonymous pipe. For Windows:
Unblocking can be achieved by adding a dummy (unbound) datagram socket to fd_set and then closing it. To make this thread safe, use QueueUserAPC:

The only way I found to make this multi-threadsafe is to close and recreate the socket in the same thread as the select statement is running. Of course this is difficult if the thread is blocking on the select. And then comes in the windows call QueueUserAPC. When windows is blocking in the select statement, the thread can handle Asynchronous Procedure Calls. You can schedule this from a different thread using QueueUserAPC. Windows interrupts the select, executes your function in the same thread, and continues with the select statement. You can now in your APC method close the socket and recreate it. Guaranteed thread safe and you will never loose a signal.

Answer (score 0):

The typical model is for the worker to handle its own writing. Is there a reason why you want to send all the output-IO through `select`ing thread?

If you're sure of this model, you could have your workers send data back to the master thread using file descriptors as well (`pipe(2)`) and simply add those descriptors to your `select()` call.

And, if you're especially sure that you're not going to use pipes to send data back to your master process, the `select` call allows you to specify a timeout. You can busy-wait while checking your worker threads, and periodically call `select` to figure out which TCP sockets to read from.

Comment: windows does not have selectable pipes

Comment: Ah. I had assumed windows implemented the POSIX spec closely. Thanks for the note.

Comment: "windows implemented the POSIX spec closely" Ohhhhh, you made me laugh. :)

Comment: @artyom, glad to lighten your day :) Thanks for educating mine. Hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick&dirty solution is to add localhost sockets to the set. Now use those sockets as the inter-thread communication queues. Each worker thread simply sends something to its socket, which ends up on the corresponding socket in your receiving thread. This wakes up the `select()`, and your receiving thread can then echo the message on the appropriate outgoing socket.

Comment: Actually, WSAWaitForMultipleEvents seems to be more or less sutable but I have to read some manuals about using it before making a decision