# How do I interrupt Socket.Select

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

How do I interrupt Socket.Select in c#?

In C I used the "self pipe" trick or "signals".

In C# I know I could create a socket pair and interrupt the select, but it doesn't seem very clean.

Is there anything better I could do to interrupt a select call in c#.

Comment: `Is there anything better I could do`, better than what? Show your code so that people can think of an asnwer. In this form it is unclear what your are asking....

Comment: See the number of answers (even with a bounty) you've got so far. What do you think? Is it because of inability of SO users or your question's quality?

Comment: The answer is simple: There is no other (portable) way. You have to add one more socket that you can control to interrupt the select (which is like self-pipe trick). Windows-only solution would be to P/Invoke some WSA...

Answer (score 1):

To solve this myself, I am just calling `Socket.Close()` on the sockets I listed in my `Socket.Select()` call. This interrupts the select with an exception.

I would use the socket pair trick, but I can’t find the equivalent to `pipe()` in .net. I have a feeling that I read somewhere that the way to do this on Windows is to connect to a loopback via TCP (especially because WSA’s `select()` doesn’t support “normal” file descriptors anyway). But that seems even dirtier and more prone to bad things happening than just closing the listening socket from a different thread and having `Socket.Select()` be interrupted with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use Socket Shutdown?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx

```
socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The best option is run select on different thread.

This helped me get rid of the exception error.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the last paramter of the `Select` function (`int microSeconds`). It servers as a timeout (-1 =  no timeout).

Comment: I am using -1 for no timeout, that's not the issue, I am trying to interrupt the select so the timeout is interrupted.

Back in C there was no real solution to interrupt it except for hacky ways such as self-pipe or signals. I was wondering if c# has any new functionality to do this without using anything "hacky".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333361/how-to-cancel-waiting-in-select-on-windows read this, same problem except in c#, the C solution is easy.

Comment: if your problem is similar the one in the other question, I would then suggest that you either use another thread to send the data or simply use the timout in Select, catch the `SocketException` and loop if you have nothing else to do in this thread (if you have something else to do in this thread (sending data for exemple), you would execute that task then restart the loop to start listening again).

Comment: My problem is only similar to it in unblocking the select statement. I don't want to add a timeout to the select, I want a way to cleanly cancel waiting on select and I have the solution in C and a dirty solution in C# but I wanted a cleaner solution if there was one available.

Comment: Then I am sorry as the only clean solution I see is the timeout. Sorry

Comment: Yeah, I thought C# would have something to signal to cancel the select like in c, but I couldn't find anything suitable.