# If Windows' select function blocks, is it always an alertable wait?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, select, winsock

I want to interrupt `select` with a non-null timeout on Windows. I'm using `QueueUserAPC` to close the waited-on socket , but I haven't convinced myself that a blocking select is **always** an alertable wait.

[QueueUserAPC function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954.aspx)

[select function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx)

> Note: When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as select with the
>   timeout parameter set to NULL, Winsock may need to wait for a network
>   event before the call can complete. ***Winsock performs an alertable
>   wait in this situation***, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous
>   procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread. Issuing another blocking
>   Winsock call inside an APC that interrupted an ongoing blocking Winsock call
>   on the same thread will lead to undefined behavior, and must never be attempted
>   by Winsock clients.

Waiting thread:

```
  timeval tv = {}
  select(socket, &tv) // block until socket is closed
```

Control thread:

```
  def CloseFunc:
     closesocket(socket)

  QueueUserAPC(CloseFunc) // enqueue the close
```

[How to cancel waiting in select() on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333361/)

Comment: If you read the various comments in the [how to cancel ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333361/) discussion more carefully, you would see this comment: "*You don't really need a pair of sockets, you can use a single UDP socket, "connected" to itself.*" You can write a byte to such a socket and it will make the same socket readable, which can satisfy `select()` that is monitoring that socket for readability.

Comment: You would have to test it (or reverse engineer it) to be sure, but if `select()` always uses an alertable wait on a NULL timeout, it stands to reason that it likely also uses an alertable wait on a non-NULL timeout.  Otherwise, if you really need to guarantee an alertable wait, use [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219.aspx) instead of `select()`.

Comment: I don't want to write to the socket, either. I'm removing the note because it's just adding noise to the discussion.

Comment: "Stands to reason" is not useful. Does the documentation guarantee an alertable wait if select will block? That's what I think the documentation says but I'm looking for agreement from others.

Comment: You would not be writing to the original socket that you are using for I/O, you would be writing to a secondary socket that is used exclusively for waking up `select()`.  As for the documentation, it only guarantees an alertable wait on a NULL timeout, it makes no mention of the implementation used for a non-NULL timeout.  So we are left guessing/experimenting/hacking to find out

Comment: I think the docs say "a blocking Winsock call* performs an alertable wait." You don't? (*e.g., select with a NULL timeout) I don't need to guarantee the APC runs unless select actually would block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79708/discussion-between-cat-zimmermann-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: That select call doesn't look like it will work at all; the argument you're depending on is ignored according to the documentation.  It shouldn't even compile, since it has the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Harry, it's pseudo-code.